# Hacer un Query en Firestore utilizando 2 propiedades dentro de un documento

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
//Count y Maxcount estan dentro de la colleción door en un documento.
db.collection("door").where("count","<","maxcount")

//Asi 
Door -> someID -> count: 9 maxcount: 10
```

Como puedo lograrlo.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta Eduardo.

Comment: Increiblemente alguien si le entendio... quizas sabe del tema.

Comment: *La unica alternativa que tienes por ahora es traer todos los datos y hacer esa comparación por fuera.*  Significa que es muy probable que debas re-plantearte la forma en que tienes organizados los datos. No es normal que para hacer un filtro tengas que traerte todo y luego hacer comparaciones por fuera. Cuando lleguen a ser varias decenas de miles o millones de registros ya imaginas lo que va a pasar.

Comment: Despues de analizarlo detenidamente, se me ocurrio que al momento de registrar y vea que llego al maximo, ponga un valor que sea true o false, así podre compararlo desde afuera. Solo queria saber si era posible hacer lo que decia

Comment: `Firebase`, por decirlo de alguna manera, rompe algunos esquemas tradicionales sobre la forma de estructurar datos. Recomiendo que leas el apartado [*Estructura tu base de datos*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)  en la documentación. Allí se explican algunas técnicas para evitar tener que traer cientos o miles o millones de datos para luego buscar el dato que quieres. Según tu aplicación, tienes que estructurar los datos de forma que puedas llegar a ellos o filtrar de una manera adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible lo que quieres hacer, al menos por ahora. Como bien menciona la documentación:

> El método where() usa tres parámetros: un campo para filtrar, una operación de comparación y un valor. La comparación puede ser <, <=, ==, > o >=. Para iOS, Android y Java, el operador de comparación se nombra de forma explícita en el método.

Por lo tanto, el 3er parametro que intentas usar como campo, en realidad es un valor contra el que comparar y va a ser tomado como un string 'maxcount'.
La unica alternativa que tienes por ahora es traer todos los datos y hacer esa comparación por fuera.

Fuente: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es-419